# Youtube embed videos not playing

Tags: android, iframe, youtube, cordova

So I've been trying to embed Youtube videos inside my phonegap Android app using the new youtube iframe API. The embed itself working and a youtube window pops in with the preview picture and the play button in the centre. The problem is when I click the button to start streaming the video the embed doesn't play the video - just loads the preview picture in and does nothing. The code used is below if it helps.

```
<iframe title="YouTube video player" class="youtube-player" type="text/html" width="320" height="194" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/xxxxxxxx" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

It works great inside a browser, but not inside the app so far. Maybe it's a Phonegap issue? Any insight would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: May  be you might need to enable plugins

Answer (score 3):

The solution for me was to set a Uses Permission of android.permission.WAKE_LOCK in the Android Manifest file.

Given that you are using phonegap, you will have to investigate how that framework allows you to manipulate Uses Permissions.